# php Phing exit task

Tags: php, phing

I have added task to build.xml to check certain condition for deployment e.g require os version and fail if requirements are not meet . e. g

```
<fail message="Required OS: '${deploy.require_os_version}' does not match with: '${remote_os}'"/>
```

Which is working but this outputs the whole error stack. Is there better way to send build failure signal and exit with decent error message ?

Comment: have you got a parse xsl ? then `xsltproc  parse.xsl` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709160/how-to-beautify-the-output-of-phing

Comment: no I don't have that. It seems this is open bug e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663869/how-to-fail-phing-without-triggering-backtrace

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question.  I think the only solution is to nest your tasks in an `if`/`then`/`else` to ensure the failure condition leads to an `<echo>` and then make sure you have no tasks defined after the `if` block.

When you think about it, this is perhaps more programmatically correct than using a task to force an early exit under expected conditions.

Comment: I am using `if-then-else` and in `else` block I using `<error>` .The question is on limiting output stack when error is thrown and beautify the output.Thanks

Comment: You can't stop the stacktrace appearing when using `<fail>`.  The only alternative is to use `<echo>`.  You can specify a `level` of `error` to display your message in red. I.e. `<echo level="error">Oh, dear!</echo>`.  The only catch is that `<fail>` causes the script to exit, and `<echo>` won't, so you need to structure your task appropriately if you need it to end after echoing the message.